# How to close a file by number?

Tags: ruby

For example, something like:

```
i = 3
close(i)
```

Suppose 3 is an open file descriptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `IO` object in order to call `IO#close` on it:

```
io = IO.for_fd(3)
# Actually, `for_fd` is just an alias for `new`, but it reads nice here

io.close

# or simply
IO.for_fd(3).close
```

In fact, even just saying

```
IO.for_fd(3)
```

without the call to `close` might be enough, because we didn't assign the returned `IO` to any variable, it is eligible for garbage collection and might eventually get garbage collected at some unspecified time in the future and the finalizer will `close` it … but relying on that is a really bad idea, since you don't know *when* the object will get garbage collected. If the program never runs out of memory, it might actually not get collected at all.